# JS: Memory leak vs Memory Bloat

Tags: javascript

I've came across with 2 definitions: a memory leak and a memory bloat.
Link there: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/
To be honest, I would like to find out difference between it. Have I understood right that the main difference is how quickly memory grows during time. If this increase is very sharp than it's a memory bloat otherwise - a memory leak. But both have one issue: GC cannot release unused memory?

Comment: What are the two definitions you found on that page?

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret that a memory leak is an issue with releasing memory, i.e. not cleaning up pointers. I do not think you can have a real memory leak in js code due to the garbage collector taking care of pointers.

Memory bloat is poor memory management in the application itself. E.g. by never flushing caches, loading unnecessary stuff, never unloading stuff from memory etc.

Comment: Yes you can have memory leaks in JS. A GC just means that you can't (or: don't have to) deallocate memory explicitly, but you still need to clean up references to things no longer used.

Comment: @EriksKlotins As for me, never flushing caches is more like memory leak since it's slowly increase a memory usage. But for the first glance I think that memory bloat doesn't lead to GC cannot reallocate unused memory.. I think that it's just when we use more memory than it's necessary... but anyway GC can release this memory later. And its critical for mobile devices for example...

Comment: @VladimirTopolev Correct. Steadily growing cache size is a memory leak, using a too large cache is memory bloat.

Comment: @Bergi I'm a little bit confused anyway. From the article from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) ```A memory leak is easy to define. If a site is progressively using more and more memory, then you've got a leak. But memory bloat is a bit harder to pin down. ``` and in [this article](http://book.scoutapp.com/memory-bloat.html) ```While memory bloat can quickly cripple a site, it’s actually easier to track down the root cause than a memory leak.``` Where is the truth?

Comment: @VladimirTopolev I think the first says that it's harder to decide when to consider memory usage as excessive, i.e. distinguish between "it's ok" and "it's a memory bloat problem". But then, once you said that you have a problem, the cause of memory bloat is easier to identify.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, memory leak and memory bloat both are sensitive issues. The basic difference between memory bloat and memory leak is, memory bloat drastically occupy(suddenly increasing) memory where memory leak is slow and continuous memory occupying process.

pictorial representation of memory leak and memory bloat is,
[image]

Have a look at this link [memory lead vs memory bloat](http://book.scoutapp.com/memory-bloat.html). I hope this will be clear.

Comment: @Bergi,  I did it. Check it will be clear or you need any more clarification